# Как из массива Integer[] сделать int[] и наоборот?

Tags: java, массивы, преобразование-типов

Добрый день изучаю преобразование данных, очень токсичная тема но знать нужно, не могли бы объяснить - как из массива Integer[] сделать int[] и наоборот?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кастованием никак, Java 8 в помощь (мне так больше нравится):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {            
    int intArray [] = {5,2,3};
    // Получение Integer[] из int[]
    Integer [] integerArray = IntStream.of(intArray).boxed().toArray(Integer []::new);
    // Получение int[] из Integer[]
     int result [] = Arrays.stream(integerArray).mapToInt(i->i).toArray();

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Прямолинейный подход - это использование цикла. Например,

```
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Integer[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        for ( int item : a ) System.out.print( item + " " );
        System.out.println();

        int[] b = new int[a.length];

        for ( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) b[i] = a[i];

        for ( int item : b ) System.out.print( item + " " );
        System.out.println();

        Integer[] c = new Integer[b.length];

        for ( int i = 0; i < b.length; i++ ) c[i] = b[i];

        for ( int item : c ) System.out.print( item + " " );
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Потрясающе, благодарю))) - гениальное решение.

Answer (score 1):

```java
int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3};

Integer[] arr2 = Arrays.stream(arr1).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);

int[] arr3 = Arrays.stream(arr2).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1)); // [1, 2, 3]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); // [1, 2, 3]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3)); // [1, 2, 3]
```